# spinner selected item is highlighted while in drop down mode android

Tags: android, spinner, baseadapter

I have a spinner populated with custom view by extending BaseAdapter. Items are populated by overriding the getView() method in BaseAdapter

I need to find a way to distinguish the selected item in the drop down list only. I mean when the user clicks on the spinner the item previously selected will show in different color/ background etc.

I don't think there is a need to see the code because it's similar to many on the site.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just use setOnItemSelectedListener? It would record the position of the spinner, and you could find if the position change.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html

Comment: I need to indicate the selection when the user clicks on the spinner and the drop down list  shows up.